# How to cast mongo collection to interface C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have a repository with signature:

```
public Task<IList<IFoo>> GetList()
{

}
```

How do I cast mongoDb collection to this interface? (MongoDb Driver 2.0)

```
public Task<IList<IFoo>> GetList()
{
    Task<List<Foo>> foo = this.database.GetCollection<Foo>("Foo").Find(e => true).ToListAsync();

    return foo ; // ?? somehow cast Task<List<Foo>> to Task<IList<IFoo>>
}
```

also, this code bothers me

```
collection.Find(e => true).ToListAsync()
```

Is there a better way to get all documents in collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 questions here.

1. How do you cast `Task<List<Foo>>` to `Task<IList<IFoo>>`?

You can't, because `Task` isn't covariant in .Net. You can unwrap the result with `await` but it still wouldn't work as you can't cast `List<Foo>` into `IList<IFoo>`.

What you can do is create a new `List<IFoo>` and cast all the items when you move them over:

```
public async Task<IList<IFoo>> GetList()
{
    List<Foo> results = await database.GetCollection<Foo>("Foo").Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();
    return results.Cast<IFoo>().ToList();
}
```

2. Is there a better way to get all documents in collection?

Not right now. You can pass in an empty filter document (`new BsonDocument()`), but I don't think it's any better. In the next version (v2.1) of the driver they've added an empty filter so you can do this:

```
await database.GetCollection<Foo>("Foo").Find(Builders<Foo>.Filter.Empty)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/query/#query-for-all-documents-in-a-collection) it says you have to call FindAsync with an empty filter to return all the documents in a collection:

> To return all documents in a collection, call the FindAsync method
>   with an empty filter document

Comment: Right, I was looking for something like List and have not noticed this, thank you.